# BIRT: How to get export option in HTML view

Tags: javascript, birt

I have the following 2 questions.

Question 1:

I need a solution in BIRT report. while I run the code in web viewer I get the export options, likewise I need the same while I run in HTML view.

do we have the export option in HTML view? if yes, anyone please give the solution.

Question 2:

Is it possible to show full page design in fixed layout? if yes, anyone please give the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question 1:

This is not possible, Instead of HTML View you can use web viewer it will render export options.

Question 2:

Yes, Goto MasterPage in your rptdesign and set height & width

```
 properties -> general -> select PageType as custom and then set height and width.
```